# Is $yf-1$ prime in $R[y]$ if $f$ not nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $f \in R$ not nilpotent. Is $yf-1$ necessarily prime in $R[y]$?

Comment: The ring $R\left[y\right] / \left(yf-1\right)$ is isomorphic to the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative subset $\left\{1, f, f^2, f^3, \ldots\right\}$. So you are asking whether this localization is necessarily an integral domain. Well... in general it won't, since $R$ itself may not be (for example, take $R$ to be your favorite non-domain, and $f = 1$). But if $R$ is an integral domain, then it will be.

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  That sounds great!  I wish I knew what the localization of $R$ at $\{1, f, f^2, \ldots \}$ meant!

Comment: @RobertLewis It's just the ring $R$ adjoin the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Thanks @darijgrinberg - will accept your solution if you copy+paste it as an answer.